# iframe won't send url variable to php across domain

Tags: php, url, get, send

I have an iframe at domain2 embedded in a main frame at domain1 that changes its location to a php file at domain1 and tries to send a variable through a url.

location change=http://www.domain1.com/phpfolder/publish.php?which=wikipedia. 
I'm trying to send the variable "which" with the url.
In the publish.php file it receives the variable called "which"

```
$whichg=$_GET["which"]; 
echo "whichg=".$whichg;
```

if the domains are the same in the iframe and the main frame the variable comes through as expected.
If the domains are different in the iframe and the main frame the variable does not come through.
I don't get any javascript errors in either case.

Also if I just paste the domain into the browser url it works fine and the php file receives the "which" variable.

Is there a way to send the "which" variable through a url from an iframe at one domain to a php file in another domain?

Edit: Some more info about the request from the net tab in console

```
Request URL:    http://www.domain1.com/phpfolder/publish.php
Request Method:     GET
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The iframe at domain2 I was talking about is actually a fancybox does that make any difference?

Comment: its possible the remote site is detecting your not legit, and is redirecting you

Comment: Watch the network tab in the console to see what the actual url being loaded is.

Comment: The iframe in domain2 is actually a fancybox. Does that change anything? I posted the network info.